# random li (list) with jQuery before page get loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

how I can random a list with jQuery before page get loaded?

i found this example on the web: http://whatanswered.com/websites-javascript/random-elements-using-jquery.php
(you must scroll down a bit to see)

but it works only after mouse press the button. *this is my problem, i need it to work atomatically before the page is getting loaded.

Any ideas?

**I copied the code in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yNChm/), if anyone would like to help, it might be usefull!**

```
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $("div.list").randomize("div.cat");
  });
});
(function($) {
$.fn.randomize = function(childElem) {
  return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var elems = $this.children(childElem);
      elems.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.8); });  
      $this.remove(childElem);  
      for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++)
        $this.append(elems[i]);      
  });    
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If the page hasn't loaded then your ul hasn't loaded. Hide the page, randomize and then show the ul on document.load.

Comment: Randomize it server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the `randomize` plugin when the page loads - be aware though the plugin needs to have been loaded before hand:

```
$(function() {      
    $("div.list").randomize("div.cat");
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yNChm/1/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to call the randomize() function after the document.ready event has fired:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("div.list").randomize("div.cat");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by doing a $(window).ready, or something along those lines:

```
$(function() {
   console.log('Yo');
   $("div.list").randomize("div.cat");
});
```

Make sure you register the plugin first!

Comment: `$(window).ready` doesn't really make sense (even though it will work). `window` in that case would be ignored, and it would instead use `document`.